# Javascript doesn't change background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the HTML code of a select box:

```
<select>
 <option onclick="bg('1.png');">Skin 1</option>
 <option onclick="bg('2.png');">Skin 2</option>
</select>
```

and here you see the function:

```
function bg(num) {
 document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/' + num + ')";
}
```

When the option `Skin 1` is selected for example, I wanna change the background of my page. But when I click on it, anything happens. Any idea?

The correct image link is: 'http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/1.png'

Comment: The string concatenation is the problem. `"url('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/" + num + "')";`

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, why not use a proper event handler ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead (no jQuery needed):

```
<select onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="1.png">Skin 1</option>
    <option value="2.png">Skin 2</option>
</select>

function bg(num) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/" + num + ")";
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2s42U/1/)** (note the second option doesn't change anything as you don't seem to have an image for that URL.)

Comment: Nice answer. It works on chrome too? I am using Mozilla, I have problems with chrome sometime

Comment: The problem was that you were concatenating the `num` variable inside the first set of double quotes. JavaScript doesn't have string interpolation, so there you can omit the single quotes, as in this answer, or you can add `.../'" + num + "'...` to properly end and start the string literals.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="1.png">Skin 1</option>
    <option value="2.png">Skin 2</option>
</select>

function bg(num) {
    var img = "http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/" + num + ".png";
    var url = "url(" + img + ")"
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = url;
}
```